# findViewById several times VS global variable

Tags: android, performance

I'm always debating what is the efficient way:
when I have to use any widgets from the xml **several times** what is better:

- to use findViewById several times
- to create a field with the findViewById result and to use this field.

I think (?) that the first option is matter of time and the second option is matter of space but what is the accepted way??

I'm android/development beginner and looking for accepted/true ways to do the things better.

Comment: the findViewById is a bit of an intensive method. i think it'd be best to use it as a private **field** especially if it's gonna be used often. note that i didn't say global since there's no reason one activity needs views in anothers.

Comment: that what i mean in global, it's really incorrect terminology. edited my question. thanks

Comment: second option is better. as `findViewById` is a heavy operation, It perform `xml` searching on all available views.

Answer (score 0):

make a method like private void initialize(){} and put all your code which uses findViewById() method.you can use this method whenever you need to initialize.
it is better to make a method inside the class rather than making a new class for that.

Comment: i'm not using a separate class, ofcourse.

Comment: @NiravTukadiya : I dont think it helped.